# Onclick event on dynamic created anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-escape-characters

I have an anchor tag which created dynamically and this anchor tag has an onclick event like this:

```
$('#'+educationHistoryId).append("<span>"+degreeTitle+"</span>" +  "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='deleteEducationLevel(" + educationHistoryId + ");'>Delete</a>");
```

when I click on this anchor I got js error saying:

**TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.**

I suspect some character escaping issue but unable to resolve.

**Added**

generated html:

```
<div id="ff8081814734be020147357beda5002b"><span>A Level</span><a onclick="deleteEducationLevel(ff8081814734be020147357beda5002b);" href="#">Delete</a></div>
```

Comment: could you make a quick fiddle with the full function of this so we know how the variables are getting set and what the html of the link looks like?  view your source code to make sure that the characters are escaping properly

Comment: Are you sure `deleteEducationLevel` is defined? Please post all your code.

Comment: have you tried using bind() istead of using inline script? http://api.jquery.com/bind/ Maybe this avoids escaping issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing that line with the following, so that the event is bound like this:

```
var $link = $("<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Delete</a>");

$link.on("click", function() {
    deleteEducationLevel(educationHistoryId);
});

$('#'+educationHistoryId).append("<span>"+degreeTitle+"</span>").append($link);
```

In my (very reduced) test, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/E7LRt/

Comment: there are multiple anchor tags which are created dynamically and having unique id.

Comment: Yes, this should still work if you replace your one line of JS with these 6 lines.

Comment: Working..Thanks Genius

Comment: Hooray! No problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

Is there an actual need to do this with just one line?
I'd suggest the following solution:

```
var $anchor = $(document.createElement("a")).attr("href","javascript:").text("Delete").on("click",function() {
    alert("clicked!");
    alert("educationHistoryId: " + educationHistoryId);
});

$("body").append("<span>" + degreeTitle + "</span> ",$anchor);
```

This works great: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/bGrmL/3/)

I always try to prevent using inline eventhandlers. It's bad practise in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Give the span a class and use event delegation.

You can then bind the click event to a existing parent(I am assuming element with `id= "#"+educationHistoryId` is existing when the event handler attachment takes place) and then delegate the event to the newly added link.

```
$("#"+educationHistoryId).on("click", <class>, function(){
 deleteEducationLevel(educationHistoryId);
});
```